# Player dies outside of collider2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im currently trying to make a Boss and there's one attack that sets an inactive animation with colliders to active once it's in that state but even if the player dodges the colliders on that animation, the player still dies. i use:

```
OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
  playerAnimation.SetTrigger("deathAnimation");
  Invoke("Restart",2f);
}
```

please help, also im sorry for my english, it is not my native language.

Comment: Obviously, your character is still colliding with the "death" colliders. You'll need to check how and why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(isDead == false)
    {
         playerAnimation.SetTrigger("deathAnimation");
         Invoke("Restart",2f);
    }
}
```

I really don't know what is happening in your code, so lets just say that the `PlayerScript` is a reference to your player's code, and the `isDead` is a bool that represents what state the thing is, well, dead.

If this does not work, then I really don't know what else would. I can't see the rest of your code! I also kind of don't know what is going on in your game. I think what you wanted to say was "the player dies when the death animation is going". Correct me if I'm wrong, and I do understand that English is not your native language.

But I hope this helps anyway!